# Smallest value of an image set function

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I need help with the following question.

Find the smallest value in the image set of the function.

$f(x) = ax^{2}+ bx + c$

where $a = 4, b = 4, c = 119$

How do I get the answer, and why?

Comment: Wellcome to MSE I hope that you would obtain a good feedback

Answer (score 1):

The image is simply the set of values that can be attained by $f(x)$. Let's look at $f(x)$:

[image]

It clearly has a minimum. Can you find it?

Comment: @Weiping If it still doesn't make sense, please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

- $4x^2+4x+119=(2x+1)^2+118$
- $(2x+1)^2\geq0$
- some $x$ exists with $(2x+1)^2=0$